# Implementation of WhatsApp/Telegram like calling feature in Flutter

Tags: flutter, background-process, phone-call

How can I implement WhatsApp/Telegram like call notification when the flutter app is in the background or cleared from the recent task (clearing ram)? Can anyone let me know Exactly How to do this?

Comment: Can you maybe describe what WhatsApp or Telegram are doing? I'm using neither, I have no idea what you are talking about...

Comment: @nvoigt I want audio/video calling feature in which the app sends push notification when arriving a call in flutter, just like whatsapp does.

Comment: I know how to do it when I am using the app, but my app needs to notify when someone calls even in background too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a great youtube series on this exact topic. In the series, a YouTuber by the name of the CS Guy creates a clone of Skype. I've placed the link to the video where he explains how to create a pop-up screen when a user calls another user, however, you may need to watch the previous videos within the series in order to get everything working. Its quite long but I recommend you watch the entire thing. In terms of displaying notifications when a user is called, I recommend you watch a video by Fireship listed below. In the video, he explains how to send notifications in the background when a certain event occurs in Firestore.

I can't explain the entire process in detail to achieve what you want but I can give a general overview of what you would need to do.

1. Watch the video/entire series by the CS Guy and complete everything
2. Learn how to send push notifications in firebase from Fireship
3. When a new document is created within the calls collection (You will understand once you finish the cs guy series) trigger cloud function.
4. Find the uid of the receiver of the call within the cloud function and grab the user's token from Firestore.
5. Finally, send a notification to the receiver telling them about the incoming call.

CS Guy:
https://youtu.be/v9ngriCV0J0

Fireship: https://youtu.be/2TSm2YGBT1s

I have done the exact same thing in my application and can help you out if you need further assistance, however, please go through both videos/series first.

Comment: If this answers your question please upvote it and accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: This method does not work, it's a hack. It works when the app is open and you're on the right screen. It's not like WhatsApp/Telegram

Comment: @AbdullahKhan how is it a hack? The notifications will be sent even if the user is not in the app.

Comment: CS Guy does not use firestore notification for incoming screen. He use stream listner which will only work when app is open. Firestore background notification doesn't work on iOS, so it will not work on iOS. Second, to wakeup android device we have to use "ConnectionServices" and for iOS "CallKit", without it we can't show real incoming screen as Whatsapp is doing and the CS Guy doesn't use any of these.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to help you.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. This only works when the app is open. If your app is closed, you won't get the notification like telegram/whatsapp. I think the OP just marked it as the best answer just because he didn't open those links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin with the [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) plugin.

From the documentation of the flutter_local_notifications plugin;

> - [Android] Support for the following notification styles
>
>   Big picture
>
>   Big text
>
>   Inbox
>
>   **Messaging**

From the documentation of the firebase_messaging plugin;

> With this plugin, your Flutter app can receive and process push notifications as well as data messages on Android and iOS.

Comment: How does I detect incoming call? The main usecase is only to detect the incoming call. I can use agora ask for the same, but it doesn't provide the way to show other user incoming call notification.

Comment: There's no 1 line answer to give you without taking a look at how your app works.  The app launches when a call comes through? You can push a notification at that time, when the app launches with an incoming call. Or you could push an 'incoming call' message through firebase messaging, and use that message to push a notification. This [article](https://medium.com/@greg.perry/notifications-in-flutter-2dc4ee6ee6aa) on notifications and [this one](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124) on executing background code will help.